# Determining Impervious Area of Parcels

Tags: polygon, field-calculator, geometry

I have parcel data for a small town and I am trying to determine the impervious area of each parcel.  I have the impervious surfaces delineated into different shapes. How do I best subtract these impervious areas from the parcels?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: You should use a symmetrical difference tool / process to basically clip out the 'non-impervious' surface leaving just the 'impervious' surface, then you'll have your area. You can do this in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to calculate the Impervious Area for each parcel, then use a Spatial Join to connect the two polygon features. You will use a one to many relationship, and specify a merge rule (sum) for your impervious areas. The join features (impervious) should probably be completely contained in the parcels. One problem we have at my agency is that our impervious area polygons are often drawn over parcel boundaries, so be watch out for that.

If you then want to subtract the impervious area from the parcel area, you can simply do a field calculation.

If you want to geometrically subtract the impervious areas from the parcels, use the Clip tool.